# I am using vb.net and i prepared report using access database. but it doesnot display any data when datasource in start-up path

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class SalesReport

 Private Sub SalesReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'loginDataSet.BillInfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.BillInfoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.loginDataSet.BillInfo)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You will need to provide more information and specifically what you mean by "datasource in start-up path".

Comment: where is data source Assignment???

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss some Code you didn't assign and datasource to your report  , Try add this line to your code :

```
Me.ReportViewer1.DataSources.Add(Me.loginDataSet.BillInfo)
```